# Why aren't allowed links not being added automatically for deep linking in android 13 devices?

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking

I'm building a flutter app with firebase's dynamic links. I know they are removing it next year but my boss wants it as a temporary solution. I've followed the steps and added everything to the manifest as well. This is the intent I've set up for deep linking

```xml
           <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="----------------"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

And this is the set up in firebase console:

[image: The setup]

and

[image: the chart]

Now, I've tried opening it on devices that runs on android 11 and it works fine. It directly takes us to the app and if it's not installed, it takes us to the fallback link. But on android 13, it goes straight to the fallback link even if app is installed. Later I found out that I have to manually add the links that are allowed to open the app. I have to go to Settings > Apps > [App name] > Open by default to do that. It works normally after that.

I've asked a few groups and communities and no one seems to have the answer. So any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Abin! Have you set up the association files correctly on the web server too?

Comment: @karllindmark You mean the assetlinks.json file? I don't think we need to do that when using firebase's dynamic links, right?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about how the Firebase Dynamic Links work in that regard (without assetlinks.json), but if your app wishes to claim the given domain in terms of Android intents, you've got to make sure it gets verified accordingly by the OS. assetlinks.json is your go-to for that!

Comment: So I did some quick reading, and the docs mention it this way: "All autoVerify intent filters in your manifest must be registered in order for App Links to engage. Firebase handles this automatically for your Dynamic Links domains, but you can check this by opening the assetlinks.json file hosted on your Dynamic Links domain: `https://YOUR_DOMAIN/.well-known/assetlinks.json`"

Comment: @karllindmark Yes, I checked it earlier today and it's there. I wish I could share the url but I don't know if I'm allowed to. But I did get the correct response.